# How to read and write on Google Sheets from my IOS app using swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, google-sheets

I am developing an app that must have a functionality to read from Google Sheets, write, and update.

I looked into the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading) and it documents how to implement it with various programming languages, but not swift. I'm wondering if there is any way to implement Google Sheets API in swift, and how would the app be able to read and write?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only official documentation from Google related to this can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/ios), although I think you may be looking for something more specific like [this one](https://github.com/adiwajshing/Queenfisher).

This second library seems a bit more documented since the creator does not just explain what it can do but it also provides examples on how to use it.

There is also [this method](https://bytepace.medium.com/work-with-google-api-in-ios-application-681a39c08037) that includes examples and images on how it works.

References:

- [First mentioned library with samples](https://github.com/adiwajshing/Queenfisher#sheets-api)
- [Second mentioned library with samples and images](https://github.com/petrovdmitriy/GoogleAPI.ios)
- [Google's "official way" with limited documentation](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest)